# Sorting files based on a timestamp within the file

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

I have a bunch of files which contain an ascii header with a time stamp **WITHIN** the file, followed by a large chunck of binary data. I would like to list the files sorted by this time stamp, at the command line (bash, etc).

The file headers look similar to the following:

```
encoding: raw
endian: big
dimension: 4
sizes: 128 128 1 4
date_time: 06.02.12.18:59
user_name: Operator1
dwell_time: 4.000

....binary data....
```

I would like to sort based on the "date_time" time stamp, which uses the format *dd.mm.yy.hh:mm*

The `sort --key` option looks promising but all my attempts have failed. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep ^date_time *.dat | sort -t: -k3
t8b.dat:date_time: 06.02.11.17:55
t8a.dat:date_time: 06.02.12.18:59
```

or to just output filenames

```
$ grep ^date_time *.dat | sort -t: -k3 | cut -d: -f1
t8b.dat
t8a.dat
```

Where the data files are

```
$ head *dat
==> t8a.dat <==
a
b
c
date_time: 06.02.12.18:59
d
e
f

==> t8b.dat <==
p
q
r
date_time: 06.02.11.17:55
x
y
z
```

You can use `grep`'s `-m 1` option to stop it searching through the subsequent (binary) data.